# C# Compiler not recognizing overloaded Main

Tags: c#, .net

Program "" has more than one entry point defined: 'Class.Main()'. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

I have searched and searched, and have only found the syntax to specify the class of the entry point, (/main:class) but not the type. Can anyone help?

```
static void Main()
{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two Main methods? Just delete the one without parameters.

Comment: Grzenio: or the other, they are both allowed. That is the underlying problem.

Comment: And then consider the overloads which return int instead of void :)

Comment: I edited off the last bit of your question, which should have been a comment.

Comment: Why are they not allowed in spite of having different signatures? Also, Jon Skeet, I tried your approach and still returned an error during compiling.

Comment: @Nona: My code definitely works, but you have to either use /main:Test or /main:Test.Parameterless to say which one you want.

Comment: (Or in Visual Studio, choose the entry point in the project properties.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this, basically.

You can only specify that a *type* is an entry point, not which Main overload *within a type* should be the entry point.

You could create a nested class containing one of them, if you want to keep the code within the same outer type:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    class Parameterless
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args){}
}
```

You then need to use either `/main:Test` or `/main:Test.Parameterless` depending on which one you want to call, or use the Application Entry Point in the project properties in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe it's possible to overload main, for that exact reason: there can be only one entry point into your program!

What the "/main" allows you to do is specify the type (i.e. the class or struct) that contains the main entry point, and not the signature (i.e. which of the overloading) so the compiler is left with ambiguity.

Comment: It's overloading, not overriding. And a type isn't the same as an assembly.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for Main() allow both forms of Main that you list, but only one should be present at any 1 time in the class. If they are in different classes you can use that to resolve the problem. What you see is the one case that isn't covered by the overloading rules.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you could try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Might not be the best method, but it would work. It is against the concepts of an application to have 2 entry points.

Comment: args will never be null, it will just be a empty string[]. if(args.Length == 0)